# Наложение элементов меню

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивность

Попросили переверстать статический сайт на HTML/CSS с табличного в блочный и сделать его адаптивным, но элементы меню при масштабировании окна браузера наезжают друг на друга, ниже код CSS и скриншот. Как можно исправить? А так же можно ли края логотипа сделать не такими резкими, без потери адаптивности? В гугле советовали только отдельно сделать изображения с полупрозрачными градиентами и наложить поверх, но вариант реализации так и не придумал. Это мой первый опыт в вёрстке.

```css
.nav a{
     padding: 5px 20px;
     background: rgba(220, 120, 173, .3);
     border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, .30);
     display:run-in ;
    }

a{
     font-size: 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-style: normal; 
     color: #fff; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="nav">   
       <a href="#">Моя биография</a>
       <a href="#">Мои увлечения</a>
       <a href="#">Мои фотографии</a>
       <a href="#">Мой софт</a>
       <a href="#">Любимые фильмы</a>
       <a href="#">Инд. задание</a></div>
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: Такой себе дизайн

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю, но меня попросили просто уже готовый сайт с табличной жесткой верстки сделать 1 в 1 только блочной резиновой версткой.

Comment: А как выглядит в табличной?

Comment: Вот в полном открытом браузере http://redline.ucoz.ua/45567654687754.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `.nav a` вместо `display:run-in` задайте значение `display: inline-block`